# Can I deploy to Heroku without a Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I followed a Django tutorial and the tutor didn't talk about the need for a Virtual Env. He deployed via Digital Ocean.  I am trying to use Heroku but just found out that I ought to have activated a Virtual Env prior to the start of my Django project.
Do I have to redo the  Django project  with a Vir Env or I can just go ahead to activate the Env and still deploy?

Comment: Have you tried it? Trying things is a fundamental skill in software development. Anyway, it's always a good idea to use a virtualenv, but this has nothing to do with Heroku. They're unrelated. As long as you've defined your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i think you can, but having a virtual environment is good practise. :) sorry if i wrong i'm new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is probably "you can still deploy" - however this depends on what tutorial you are following and what you want to archive, and cannot be answered without more information on your project. I suggest you simply try.

If you follow a tutorial that hosts a VPS webserver (e.g. from digitalocean), the necessary steps are different than if you deploy to heroku, obviously.

Read this [official heroku/django guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#python-deployment-flow) to understand the deployment process. It is very useful and comes with a step-by-step guide for deploying python apps on heroku as well.

As virtual environments are (only) a fancy way of encapsulating python projects and their dependencies, [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) is exactly what you should read (to understand the basics and important details for future deploys of all kind of python apps to heroku).

Happy coding .